# Form submitting even email already message showing Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to validate email availability using jQuery and then show an email availability message.

The message is showing successfully but the form is also submitting. I just want if I get an email availability message then 
the form should not submit. How can I do this?

```
public function check_emailp()
{
  $email = $_POST['emailid'];
  $record['data']=$this->Home->check_emailsd($email);
  if ($record['data']=="taken")
  {
    echo "<span style='color:red'> Email already exit .</span>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<span style='color:green'> Email Availiable.</span>";
  }
}
```

```
function checkemailAvailability() {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url + 'index.php/register/check_emailp',
    data: 'emailid=' + $("#email").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      $("#email-availability-status").html(data);
      $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error: function (){}
  });
}
```

```html
  <form name="myForm"  id ="myForm" action="<?php echo site_url('register/update_info'); ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Enter a Location" class="form-control" onBlur="checkemailAvailability()">
      </div>
      <?php //echo form_error('userName'); ?>
      <span id="email-availability-status"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class=" form-control btn btn-info btn-lg hoj-blue-light login-reg-btn bold post-a-job-btn">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Validate email with codeigniter form_validation library not with jQuery.

Comment: Do you mean at `onblur` form is submitting?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in 2 ways,

**Check Email Availability when submitting**

By checking email when `form submit` instead of `input onBlur`.

`<form onSubmit='return checkemailAvailability()'>`

And your JS should be like,

```
function checkemailAvailability() {

 // your implementiations
 // let's say the variable exist is the status

  if (exist) {
     return false;
  } else {
     return true;
  }

}
```

**Setting a variable, And Check it while submit**

your form

`<form onSubmit='return checkForm()'>`

your js

```
var emailExist = false;


    function checkemailAvailability() {

     // your implementiations
     // let's say the variable exist is the status

      if (exist) {
         emailExist = true;
      }

    }

   function checkForm() {

     return emailExist;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use `onClick="checkemailAvailability()"` Instead Of `onBlur="checkemailAvailability()"`

2.Best way to check ajax error with php :

```
$temp_array = array(); //Create temp array to store messages
//if error code will be here
$temp_array['error'] = "You error comment";

//if success code will be here
$temp_array['success'] = "You success comment";

echo json_encode($temp_array);
```

3.in jquery success:

```
success: function(data) {
      //Parse json data
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      if(obj.error)
      {
        //Show error message code will be here
        e.preventdefault();
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        //show success message code will be here
      }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

### **try this code**

`public function check_emailp()`
`{
  $email = $_POST['emailid'];`
 `$record['data']=$this->Home->check_emailsd($email);`

`if ($record['data']=="taken")`
`{
    echo 0;`
`}
  else`
`{
    echo 1;`
`}
}`

`function checkemailAvailability() {`
  
 `$("#loaderIcon").show();`
 
 `var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';`
 
      `jQuery.ajax({`
 
             `url: url + 'index.php/register/check_emailp',`
 
             `data: 'emailid=' + $("#email").val(),`
  
             `type: "POST",`
 
             `success: function(data) {`

`//alert(data);
               if(data==0)`
    `{
                  var msg='<span style='color:red'> Email already exit .</span>';`
    
               `} else 
                {`
    
                   `var msg='<span style='color:green'> Email Availiable.</span>';
                }`
  
          `$("#email-availability-status").html(msg);`
  
          `$("#loaderIcon").hide();`
 `},
      error: function (){}`

`});
}`